AWS Glue python script create multiple files of a specific size not working
I have below Python script where currently it generates several gz files with size 4MB in S3 bucket. Its bydeafult what AWS glue has created. But now i want to create multiple files of specific size around 100-250MB in s3 bucket. I have tried below logic in python script but it did not work and still creates several gz files with size 4MB.
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import datetime


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['target_BucketName', 'JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

outputbucketname = args['target_BucketName']

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
filename = f"tbd{timestamp}"
output_path = f"{outputbucketname}/{filename}"


# Script generated for node AWS Glue Data Catalog
AWSGlueDataCatalog_node075257312 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="ardt", table_name="_ard_tbd", transformation_ctx="AWSGlueDataCatalog_node075257312")

# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node075284688 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=AWSGlueDataCatalog_node075257312, connection_type="s3", format="csv", format_options={"separator": "|"}, connection_options={"path": output_path, "compression": "gzip",  "recurse": True, "groupFiles": "inPartition", "groupSize": "100000000"}, transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node075284688")


job.commit()


Use pandas for this :
# Convert DynamicFrame to PySpark DataFrame
df_spark = AWSGlueDataCatalog_node075257312.toDF()

# Convert PySpark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame
df_pandas = df_spark.toPandas()

# Determine the number of rows per file based on your desired file size
rows_per_file = 100000  # Adjust this number based on your data and desired file size

# Split the DataFrame into smaller DataFrames and save each to S3 in gzip format
for i in range(0, len(df_pandas), rows_per_file):
    df_chunk = df_pandas[i:i + rows_per_file]
    df_chunk.to_csv(
        f's3://your-bucket/your-output-path/part_{i // rows_per_file}.csv.gz', 
        index=False, 
        compression='gzip'
    )


i have already checked this solution and not recommended specially to use rows_per_file for large tables. Also for loop condition which you are using will have impact on high cost consumption as it requires more processing.

The groupFiles option that you're using is only used for reading data more efficiently.
You have 2 options here. The easier one would be to repartition data - but in this case you'd have to guesstimate the number of partitions beforehand.
Another possibility is to use maxRecordsPerFile Spark option:
df.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10000).save("s3://some-bucket/my-prefix/")

Again, this would require estimating the number of records required to obtain the desired file size.
Finally, the most bulletproof way you could do this (but also the most complex one) - write output of your job without regard for file sizes, look at the average file size, then re-read, repartition and write again.

If you see the below answer comment also, i have mentioned if i provide maxRecordsPerFile then i think it will affect on processing speed which will consume more cost as well because it will try to check every file and number of records to process per file. The partition logic from aws will not work here i guess
